# How can I suppress vertical scrollbar in fancybox iframe pop-up?

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using fancybox (latest version, downloaded today) to create an iframe pop-up, using snippets gleaned here, mainly. By default, the fancybox popup can be closed either by clicking on the close button or outside the pop-up area. What want is...

- popup with max width and height but scales to fit different
  device-widths
- no scrollbars
- a close button, but no closing with an
  outside click.

The code so far:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
modal : true,
maxWidth    : 800,
maxHeight   : 420,
autoSize    : true,
autoWidth: true,
autoHeight : true,
fitToView: true,
closeClick  : false,
hideOnOverlayClick : false,
hideOnContentClick : false,
enableEscapeButton : false,
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
padding : 0,
margin : 0,
showCloseButton : true,
scrolling : 'no',
afterShow : function() {
$('.fancybox-skin').append('<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"
href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a>');
}
});
```

With that, the content (swf and swiffy files) scales to fill the viewport horizontally, only the close button closes the popup, and there are no horizontal scrollbars (I think because in the css I moved the close button's position, which was off-screen thanks to the margin:0, onto the content area).

The only problem now is that a vertical scrollbar has appeared on the right of the popup iframe (within the iframe) at every device-width, from 320px to 1280px (even though there's nothing to scroll for). I have included scrolling : 'no' and changed scrolling : 'auto' to scrolling : 'no' in the jquery.fancybox.js defaults, but it hasn't helped.

Anybody know how to get rid of the scrollbars?

Comment: try css style: overflow:hidden; like $('.fancybox').css({'overflow':'hidden'})

Comment: Got it! In the fancybox CSS file changed .fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {overflow: auto;overflow-y: scroll;} to .fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {overflow: hidden;overflow-y: hidden;} Thanks for putting me on the track.

Comment: "Upvote a comment by clicking on the up arrow that appears when you hover the mouse over the comment." But no arrow appears,,,